# Select count of customer ID with multiple orders over rolling date range

Tags: oracle, date, subquery, aggregate

I have data which looks something like this:

```
order_date  phone_number  order_number
----------  ------------  ------------
18/03/2015  0912345678    123
27/03/2015  0912345678    176
18/03/2015  0973541893    453
20/03/2015  0565741534    678    
03/04/2015  0565741534    534
```

I want to be able to write a query which, based on 'order_date' looks over the today and the previous 9 days (or any other number of days) as a 10-day rolling window, and return the count of 'phone_number' that have multiple orders, and, the count of 'phone_number' that has a single order, e.g.

```
date_from   date_to      count_multiple  count_single
----------  -----------  --------------  ------------
18/03/2015  27/03/2015   5               15
19/03/2015  28/03/2015   7               10
20/03/2015  29/03/2015   6               11
21/03/2015  30/03/2015   3               17
```

I can do the date calculation part of the SELECT statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_date - 9 AS date_from, order_date AS date_to
FROM orders
WHERE order_date > ((SELECT MIN(order_date) FROM orders) + 9)
ORDER BY order_date;
```

...and I can get what I want if I specify exact parameters, e.g., for multiple orders between 18 and 28 March, 2015:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT phone_number, count(order_number) FROM orders
  WHERE order_date BETWEEN to_date('18/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
                       AND to_date('27/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  HAVING COUNT(order_number) > 1
  GROUP BY phone_number
) multiple_orders
```

...and the same for single orders...

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT phone_number, count(order_number) FROM orders
  WHERE order_date BETWEEN to_date('18/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
                       AND to_date('27/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  HAVING COUNT(order_number) = 1
  GROUP BY phone_number
) single_orders
```

However, I cannot figure out how to include these in the main SELECT clause as subqueries, based on the first two date columns.

I would like to write something like this:

```
SELECT 
  o.order_date - 9 AS date_from, 
  o.order_date AS date_to,
  (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT x.phone_number, COUNT(x.order_number) FROM orders x 
      WHERE x.order_date BETWEEN (o.order_date - 9)
                             AND  o.order_date
      HAVING COUNT(x.order_number) > 1
      GROUP BY x.phone_number
    )
  ) AS Has_Multiple, 
  (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT x.phone_number, COUNT(x.order_number) FROM orders x 
      WHERE x.order_date BETWEEN (o.order_date - 9)
                             AND  o.order_date
      HAVING COUNT(x.order_number) = 1
      GROUP BY x.phone_number
    )
  ) AS Has_Single 
FROM orders o
WHERE o.order_date > ((SELECT MIN(order_date) FROM orders) + 9)
ORDER BY o.order_date;
```

Of course, the above doesn't work, but what I'm really looking for is the ability to have each of the counts in columns 3 and 4 be based off columns 1 and 2 (with 1 being calculated from 2).

Current error is:

```
ORA-00904: "O"."ORDER_DATE": invalid identifier
```

Note, I don't get any error if I don't include the subqueries in the SELECT statement. So it seems I'm not doing the subquery correctly as the main query cannot 'see' inside the nested subquery :(

I have found all the individual components by searching here, and on Google... but I can't seem to combine them... especially with this 'rolling date window' concept.

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: You mean to say, when you included your subqueries to your main queries then, it doesn't work ? But, what is happening. For me, you query seems to be working.

Comment: If you are getting any error, then include otherwise include the expected output and current output.

Comment: Thanks @jWeaver! I'll include the error now, and adjust a typo in the query (I'm having to 'sanitise' these as these are based on corporate data)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your aim by using analytic functions with an appropriate windowing clause. Since you didn't provide sample input data that matches with your expected output data, I've had to provide my own - I can only assume that I've got the logic correct, though; you'd have to doublecheck it. I reduced the window from 9 to 3 days (well, technically I suppose it's from 10 to 4 days, but who's counting?! *{;-) )

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 1 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 1 dt from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 2 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 1 dt from dual union all
                     select 3 id, 3 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 1 dt from dual union all
                     select 4 id, 1 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 2 dt from dual union all
                     select 5 id, 2 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 2 dt from dual union all
                     select 6 id, 4 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 2 dt from dual union all
                     select 7 id, 4 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 3 dt from dual union all
                     select 8 id, 1 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 3 dt from dual union all
                     select 9 id, 7 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 3 dt from dual union all
                     select 10 id, 6 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 4 dt from dual union all
                     select 11 id, 6 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 4 dt from dual union all
                     select 12 id, 5 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 4 dt from dual union all
                     select 13 id, 6 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 5 dt from dual union all
                     select 14 id, 9 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 5 dt from dual union all
                     select 15 id, 3 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 5 dt from dual union all
                     select 16 id, 2 num, trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 6 dt from dual),
             res as (select id,
                            num,
                            dt st_dt,
                            dt + 3 end_dt,
                            count(*) over (partition by num order by dt
                                           range between current row and 3 following) cnt_num_curr_and_next_3_days
                     from   sample_data)
select st_dt,
       end_dt,
       count(case when cnt_num_curr_and_next_3_days > 1 then 1 end) count_multiple,
       count(case when cnt_num_curr_and_next_3_days = 1 then 1 end) count_single
from   res
group by st_dt,
         end_dt
order by st_dt;

ST_DT      END_DT     COUNT_MULTIPLE COUNT_SINGLE
---------- ---------- -------------- ------------
02/07/2015 05/07/2015              2            1
03/07/2015 06/07/2015              2            1
04/07/2015 07/07/2015              0            3
05/07/2015 08/07/2015              2            1
06/07/2015 09/07/2015              0            3
07/07/2015 10/07/2015              0            1
```

---

The more I look at this, the more I think maybe that analytic functions can't do the job, at least not on their own.

It's possible that a model clause would be the best solution, but unfortunately, I'm no expert at models!